# Is this possible or hopeless to try to prove?

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, approximation

If I have $x_1, ..., x_k=o(n)$ and $j=O(1)$.

Is it possible to prove something like:

$$\sum_{i=1}^k {n \choose j} \left(\frac{x_i}{n}\right)^j \left(1-\frac{x_i}{n}\right)^{k-j} \sim {n \choose j} \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^j \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{k-j}$$

where $x:=\sum_{i=1}^k x_i$.

Is there any hope to prove that or should I let it be?

Or could one approximate this term by some other Definition for $x$?

The simplified term is then:
$$\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^j \left(n-x_i\right)^{k-j} \sim x^j \left(n-x \right)^{k-j}$$

Comment: The $\binom n j$ is a constant on both sides, so you can eliminate that...

Comment: I'd let $y_i=\frac{x_i}{n}$ to get a simpler expression, with no more need for the $n$ since $y_i=o(1)$.

Comment: I know that one could simplify this term, at the beginning I posted the simplified term. But I thought, maybe it could help someone to see the context. So I added it.

Comment: It's not clear how the 'context' clarifies anything here. If you've done some work, show the work! You didn't give the simpler form, so how would anybody trying to help you avoid duplicating that work?

Comment: It's not clear what $x_i=o(n)$ means. Does $x_i$ change when $n$ changes - that is, is $x_i$ really $x_i(n)$?

Comment: So I added the simplified Version, I hope I did not make a mîstake. 

$x_i=o(n)$ means that for every $i$ we have a $x_i(n)$, e.g. $x_i=\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Answer (score 2):

By exploiting the convexity/concavity (depending on $j$) of $(x(1-x))^j$ over $[0,1]$, you always have an inequality in a certain direction through the Jensen's inequality, but to prove that your inequality holds even in the opposite direction (up to a constant factor) you need stronger assumptions con the distribution of the $x_i$s.

Comment: thank you for your answer. What would be enough to be able to Show this? Do you know this? This would really help me!

Comment: would for example a geometric Distribution over the $x_i$ help?

Comment: A classical example is given by the moments of a random variable. We always have $\mathbb{E}[X^n]\geq(\mathbb{E}[X])^n$, but to prove $\mathbb{E}[X^n]\leq K\cdot(\mathbb{E}[X])^n$ requires additional information on the distribution of $X$. It is true for normal distributions, for example.

Comment: To prove the "converse Jensen's" inequality is is worth to consider the characteristic function of the distribution. If it is an analytic function, we're good. So, yes, assuming that the $x_i$s are geometrically distributed allows to prove the inequality in the opposite direction. It is rather technical, however.

Comment: thank you for your answer! this really helped. So this would give an upper and a lower bound (Jensen and converse Jensen) and thus together one would have an asymptotic bound?
Is there a paper that does derive this converse Jensen inequality?
How can one state the assumption about the analytic function? Can one give an easy condition depending on the mean, variance,...?
Would you mind to expand your solution a Little bit? It would be really helpful, but I didn't study maths and so I am a bit .. overchallenged. But it would really help me!

Comment: A large piece of mathematics is dedicated to reverse inequalities (see, for example, http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177697526). All the issues here relies on the distribution of $X^j(1-X)^{k-j}$ - mean and variance are not enough to state the reverse inequality (there are a lot of distribution with the same mean and variance of yours for which the reverse inequality does not hold), but if you know something about how fast the pdf of $X$ or $X^j(1-X)^{k-j}$ decay at infinity you are on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for the link and the Explanation. 
Would it be enough to assume that after some Point $l\ll n$ we have that $Pr[X \geq l] \ll \frac{1}{n}$?
Under These assumption one can Show this?
If you would not mind, I would really really appreciate, if you could Show me the Argumentation process to derive this. 
E.g. in the following sense:
"With Theorem .. you get .."
At this Point, I have not enough skills in mathematics yet to understand the whole proof with each Detail. But I would really appreciate help, because I feel lost when I have a look at this paper. And it's not that i am too lazy.

Comment: I looked at it (this paper) the whole time and tried to find a proof for this. But it didn't work. Could you tell me, whether $Pr[X\geq l] \ll \frac{1}{n}$ is enough to assume? 
And could you give me some hints, how to prove it? I really am willing to do work on my own, but it is that i am stuck now and really would appreciate help!

Comment: No, it is not enough. The Cauchy distribution has such a property but $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ do not even exists. An exponential decay of the pdf should be enough in virtue of the Paley-Wiener theorem.

Comment: Ok, thank you!
I am not sure, but does this really give me a relative error?
As I would Need to prove that the relative error is in $o(1)$, as I want to prove $f(x)=g(x)(1+o(1))$, where $f$ is the Expression from above with the sum over the $x_i$ and $g$ is the Expression with $x$?
Theorem 1 in the paper gives me a possibility to Change $E$ and the sum, but it gives a constant factor. This would Need to be divided by the term $f$ to give a relative error. 
So I am a Little bit stuck here.

Comment: Even assuming that the distribution of $X$ is regular enough to make the reverse Jensen's inequality true, you will never have something like $f\sim g$, but just $f\ll g$ and $g\ll f$, with one of the two hidden constants being one. I think you cannot really get rid of the other constant, so there is no "relative error".

Comment: How can it be that $f\ll g$ and $g\ll f$? Isn't this a contradiction?

And: Would there be an other $x$ (defined not as the sum of the $x_i$), such that one could prove $f\sim g$?

Comment: It is the Vinogradov notation. If $f$ is always between $\frac{1}{2}g$ and $2g$, for example, $f\ll g$ and $g\ll f$. No contradiction at all.

Comment: After googling, I am not sure whether I have the same "Notation" here: 
For me: $f \sim g$ means that $lim \frac{f}{g}=1$ and $f\ll g$ means that $lim \frac{f}{g}=0$. 
So with this Notation, it does not hold that $f \ll \frac{1}{2} g$. But I see that one would have Trouble with proving $f \sim g$. So even with another choice of $x$?

Comment: No, $f\ll g$ means that the ratio $\frac{f}{g}$ is bounded. The notation for $\lim\frac{f}{g}=0$ is $f=o(g)$. Also notice that if the gap between $\min f$ and $\max f$ over the possible sequences is big, there is no possible choice of $x$ that can close such gap.

Comment: In my paper, there is another Definition of $f \ll g$, so this must have lead to some misunderstandings, I am sorry. 
Thank you for your help! But it seems as if this is not what I am looking for. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Notation, naturally, varies with sub-field and author preferences. In the papers I tend to read, $f\ll g$    means $f=o(g)$; whereas $f\lesssim g$ is used for $f=O(g)$. Just a data point.